Sound to samples not working
Inserted a keyframe in Shape Keys Key 1 Value (Relative checked).
Graph editor:Clicked sound to samples, downloaded audio.
f-curve shows up. Play animation,nothing happens.
Please help. Thank you

It should work right out of the box, so you'd better check some obvious things, like the corrispondance between the name in the graph editor with the name of the shape key, and the values shown in graph with the value of the shape key.

If this doesn't solve, please upload your file, packing your audio (Menu File > External data > Pack Resources).

Hello Josh, Attempting to pack the file, I cannot pack the file because I get an error saying: dried ground brush not found. And I cannot find it either. Comment? Cheers

It didn't pack that brush, but it did pack others external resources, including sounds.

How do I upload the file?

https://blend-exchange.com/

Josh :  I do not understand what just happened. I made a small copy of the file to send to you. Then the animation worked. And I went back to the original file, and now the animation works. Have not the foggiest. I spent a week or more trying to get this to work, and without doing any new, now it works.  ??? Tk

By the way, could you tell me how to continue packing the file automatically by somehow getting rid of the dried ground brush which prevents the file from automatically packing resources.
